# Showing empty record in RadGrid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, rad-controls

Friends I'm working with one level hierarchy  grid. I'm doing code as below

```
protected DataSet GenerateRadGrid()
    {
        DataSet dsCollective = new DataSet();
        DataSet dsFirst = Library.ExecuteTag("SelectEHRMessage");
        if (dsFirst.HasRows())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dsFirst.Tables[0].Copy();
            dt.TableName = "MainMessage";
            dsCollective.Tables.Add(dt);
            foreach (DataRow row in dsCollective.Tables["MainMessage"].Rows)
            {
                var rootMessageID = row["MessageID"].ToFormatedInt64();
                DataSet dsSecond = Library.ExecuteTag("SelectParentReply", new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@0", rootMessageID));
                dsSecond.Tables[0].TableName = "MainReplies-" + rootMessageID;
                dsCollective.Tables.Add(dsSecond.Tables[0].Copy());
                DataRelation mainMessageRepliesRelation = new DataRelation("MainMessageReplies-" + rootMessageID, dsCollective.Tables["MainMessage"].Columns["MessageID"], dsCollective.Tables["MainReplies-" + rootMessageID].Columns["MessageID"]);
                dsCollective.Relations.Add(mainMessageRepliesRelation);

            }

        }
        return dsCollective;
    }
```

that's the function that return me the dataset which I'm binding with the grid. Now the problem is that the grid show's me the empty record too. I mean in which the relation is not there. as below:

[image]

now what i have to change in the code to avoid those "No child record to display" row. Is there any property that work for me?

Answer (score 2):

You set two things, `ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords` and `NoDetailRecordsText`. For child grids you set that on the `GridTableView` nested within `DetailTables`, but you can set that on your `MasterTableView` as well if you don't want headers on the main grid either.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdMain" runat="server">
        <MasterTableView ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="false" NoDetailRecordsText="">
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="false" NoDetailRecordsText="" />
            </DetailTables>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: where i add this. In aspx page i have only <telerik:RadGrid> tag, not <telerik:GridTableView>

Comment: @NomiAli I have added a more complete example. I was initially referring to the child GridTableView within your DetailTables collection inside the RadGrid's MasterTableView.

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateHierarchy="true"/>

Comment: If you want to tweak your hierarchy results you won't be able to use `AutoGenerateHierarchy` unless you do some magic in the OnDataBound and ItemCreated events.

Comment: Look at this demo at the Telerik site: [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/declarativerelations/defaultcs.aspx) Down at the bottom it shows the markup for configuring hierarchical grids without using autogenerate.

Comment: thanks for the demo! buts that create the grid on the aspx. I'm doing at .cs file through DataRelation.

Comment: The code you posted creates a DataSet with relationships, it doesn't actually do anything with RadGrid at all. In `RadGrid1_NeedDataSource` you are binding RadGrid to the DataSet and it is automagically generating columns and child views because you have `AutoGenerateHierarchy` set to true. If you want more control over how your RadGrid looks and displays data, your best option is to change the declarative markup. Use the demo as an example for how to do your markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the NoDetailRecordsText property to empty string

```
<telerik:GridTableView NoDetailRecordsText="">
```

Comment: Do you have a <MasterTableView> tag inside the <telerik:RadGrid>? Try to put the NoDetailRecordsText="" attribute there.

Comment: i have only: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateHierarchy="true"/> on aspx.